# does PHP not have cross-domain issue while getting json?

Tags: javascript, php, json, cross-domain

```
jQuery.ajax({'url':'http://67.20.67.232/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=2&Itemid=150&lang=zh-cn&format=json'})
// don't mind the long url string, you just need to know it outputs valid json
```

This won't work under a different domain because of the cross-domain limitation. But it seems I can use

```
file_get_contents('http://67.20.67.232/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=2&Itemid=150&lang=zh-cn&format=json');
```

to get the json string in PHP. So does this cross-domain limitation not apply to PHP? Is it because PHP is running on server side while javascript on client-side? I am not very familiar with node.js but I kind of understand that it is running on server-side, so would the 1st snippet work for node.js?

Comment: yes, yes, yes, yes. there is no such thing as cross-domain limitation server-wise

Comment: You need to understand why the SOP exists (cookies).  Read Wikipedia.